# post.next and post.prev in single.twig after a custom query

Tags: wordpress, timber

I am having trouble with post.next and post.prev in my single.twig file. The query is on a custom post type but also for a specific taxonomy term. The archive page displays the correct posts, but if I click on an item and go into single.twig, the next and prev buttons cycle through ALL the posts the custom post type, not just the ones which contain the specified taxonomy term. Is this something that is supported in Timber? If not, can someone help me write a function for it in my functions.php?

I have even tried over-writing the default query. Here is the code that's in my archive.php file:

```
global $paged;
if (!isset($paged) || !$paged){
    $paged = 1;
}
$context = Timber::get_context();
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'credits', //this is the CPT 
    'orderby' => 'menu_order', 
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => '999', 
    'paged' => $paged,
    /*
    'meta_query' => array(
       array(
           'key' => 'video',
           'value' => 'yes',
           'compare' => '=',
       )
    )  
    */ 
    'tax_query' => array(
        array (
            'taxonomy' => 'auto_taxonomies',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'in-film-archive',
        )
    )

);
/* THIS LINE IS CRUCIAL */
/* in order for WordPress to know what to paginate */
/* your args have to be the defualt query */
query_posts($args);
/* make sure you've got query_posts in your .php file */
$context['posts'] = Timber::get_posts();
$context['pagination'] = Timber::get_pagination();
var_dump($context['pagination']);
Timber::render('archive-films.twig', $context);
```

This is the code I have in the single.twig file:

```
<div class="post-nav">
  {% if post.prev(true) != null %}
    <div class="prev-film two columns"><a href="{{post.prev.link}}">{{post.prev(true).title}}</a></div>
  {% endif %}
  {% if post.next(true) != null %}
    <div class="next-film two columns"><a href="{{post.next.link}}">{{post.next(true).title}}</a></div>
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

Do I need to add anything specific to my single.php file?

Comment: It looks like you followed the pagination guide in the wiki, which is deprecated and will be deleted very soon. The [official guide for Pagination](https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/pagination/) with Timber shows you how you can use the `PostQuery` class, which possibly fixes your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I figured it out myself.

In functions php I added:

```
//custom next post within taxonomy term
function custom_next_post($post_id){
    $next_post = get_adjacent_post( true, '', true, 'tax slug goes here' );
    if (is_a($next_post, 'WP_Post')){
        echo "<a href=" . get_permalink($next_post->ID) . ">" . get_the_title($next_post->ID) . "</a>";
    }
}

//custom prev post within taxonomy term
function custom_prev_post($post_id){
    $next_post = get_adjacent_post( true, '', false, 'tax slug goes here' );
    if (is_a($next_post, 'WP_Post')){
        echo "<a href=" . get_permalink($next_post->ID) . ">" . get_the_title($next_post->ID) . "</a>";
    }
}
```

and in the single.twig file I added:

```
{# PAGINATION - THESE CALL A CUSTOM FUNCTION IN FUNCTIONS.PHP TO CYCLE ONLY WITHIN OUR TAXONOMY TERM  #}    
<div class="post-nav">
    <div class="prev-film two columns">{{function('custom_prev_post',post.id)}}</div>
    <div class="next-film two columns">{{function('custom_next_post',post.id)}}</div>
</div>
```